# Leitor de QRCode JavaScript

Tags: javascript, qrcode

Estou utilizando o [QR Scanner](https://github.com/nimiq/qr-scanner) para tentar fazer a leitura de códigos QR através de cameras de dispositivos *mobile*, porém é detectado a câmera do dispositivo mas **não mostra nenhuma imagem da câmera na aplicação**.

> Device has camera: **true**

Realizei o download dos arquivos minificados especificados abaixo e foi modificado o Path corretamente de cada um no modulo como no código abaixo.

> qr-scanner.min.js
>
> qr-scanner-worker.min.js

O meu documento está apenas com o código de exemplo que eles apresentam, mesmo assim nada é apresentado e nenhum erro é mostrado no console. Alguem poderia me ajudar?

```js
<script type="module">
  import QrScanner from "../../Scripts/QRScanner/qr-scanner.min.js";
  QrScanner.WORKER_PATH = '../../Scripts/QRScanner/qr-scanner-worker.min.js';


  const video = document.getElementById('qr-video');
  const debugCheckbox = document.getElementById('debug-checkbox');
  const debugCanvas = document.getElementById('debug-canvas');
  const debugCanvasContext = debugCanvas.getContext('2d');
  const camHasCamera = document.getElementById('cam-has-camera');
  const camQrResult = document.getElementById('cam-qr-result');
  const fileSelector = document.getElementById('file-selector');
  const fileQrResult = document.getElementById('file-qr-result');

  function setResult(label, result) {
    label.textContent = result;
    label.style.color = 'teal';
    clearTimeout(label.highlightTimeout);
    label.highlightTimeout = setTimeout(() => label.style.color = 'inherit', 100);
  }

  // ####### Web Cam Scanning #######

  QrScanner.hasCamera().then(hasCamera => camHasCamera.textContent = hasCamera);

  const scanner = new QrScanner(video, result => setResult(camQrResult, result));
  scanner.start();

  document.getElementById('inversion-mode-select').addEventListener('change', event => {
    scanner.setInversionMode(event.target.value);
  });

  // ####### File Scanning #######

  fileSelector.addEventListener('change', event => {
    const file = fileSelector.files[0];
    if (!file) {
      return;
    }
    QrScanner.scanImage(file)
      .then(result => setResult(fileQrResult, result))
      .catch(e => setResult(fileQrResult, e || 'No QR code found.'));
  });


  // ####### debug mode related code #######

  debugCheckbox.addEventListener('change', () => setDebugMode(debugCheckbox.checked));

  function setDebugMode(isDebug) {
    const worker = scanner._qrWorker;
    worker.postMessage({
      type: 'setDebug',
      data: isDebug
    });
    if (isDebug) {
      debugCanvas.style.display = 'block';
      worker.addEventListener('message', handleDebugImage);
    } else {
      debugCanvas.style.display = 'none';
      worker.removeEventListener('message', handleDebugImage);
    }
  }

  function handleDebugImage(event) {
    const type = event.data.type;
    if (type === 'debugImage') {
      const imageData = event.data.data;
      if (debugCanvas.width !== imageData.width || debugCanvas.height !== imageData.height) {
        debugCanvas.width = imageData.width;
        debugCanvas.height = imageData.height;
      }
      debugCanvasContext.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    }
  }
</script>
<style>
  canvas {
    display: none;
  }

  hr {
    margin-top: 32px;
  }

  input[type="file"] {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
  }
</style>
<h1>Scan from WebCam:</h1>
<div>
  <b>Device has camera: </b>
  <span id="cam-has-camera"></span>
  <br>
  <video id="qr-video"></video>
  <canvas id="debug-canvas"></canvas>
</div>
<div>
  <select id="inversion-mode-select">
    <option value="original">Scan original (dark QR code on bright background)</option>
    <option value="invert">Scan with inverted colors (bright QR code on dark background)</option>
    <option value="both">Scan both</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="debug-checkbox">
  <label for="debug-checkbox">Show debug image</label>
</div>
<b>Detected QR code: </b>
<span id="cam-qr-result">None</span>
<hr>

<h1>Scan from File:</h1>
<input type="file" id="file-selector">
<b>Detected QR code: </b>
<span id="file-qr-result">None</span>
```

Obs: A leitura de QR Code através de um arquivo de imagem pré-selecionado funciona perfeitamente.

Obs2: Fiz uns testes em diferentes dispositivos e vi que é uma particularidade do Android a regra de não mostrar nenhuma imagem.

Obs3: Por fim optei por retirar o código por não poder oferecer suporte a todos os tipos de dispositivos, mas gostaria ainda de saber a resposta

Comment: Você está rodando o HTML direto ? abrindo como arquivo no browser? Se sim, tente usar um servidor para isso. Pode ser que o navegador esteja bloqueando, já tive problemas com isso. Use o https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server e rode o server na sua pasta local só para testar. É bem simples, instale a lib global e digite http-server na mesma pasta do html, ai abra pelo servidor e teste denovo

Comment: Na verdade estou usando um servidor do IIS para rodar a aplicação.

Comment: O `import` do lado do browser não é default em todos os browsers ainda... Pode estar ocorrendo de alguns navegadores que você usa no android não suportar esse tipo de import

Comment: Veja as versões suportadas https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Compatibilidade_entre_navegadores